# C++, Qt - Hideable QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qlistview

I would like to make a list of checkboxes for my programm, so that the users are be able to check/uncheck a number of different flags. However, I would like to make it behave like a QComboBox: to be folded most of the time, but to open itself when clicked.

What is the best way to add such functionality (e.g. derive a custom class from QComboBox, or do something with a QListView)? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for it on the Qt forum:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7740

It recommends the usage of a custom model/view, based on the tutorial `2_formatting` in the examples folder.

Comment: Thanks, seems it is going to help, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own `QWidget` that has a `QCheckBox` and the `QComboBox`.

Make signals and slot connections  between the checkbox and the combobox.

Add your custom widget to the `QListWidget` using [QListWidget::setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget)..

Using this you can add custom widgets to your QListWidget.

Hope that helps.